# Interface Builder and NSTableView top constraint

Tags: macos, user-interface, autolayout, interface-builder, nstableview

I have the following UI definition:

[image: UI Hierarchy]

I wanted to define the constraints for the components but whenever I try to add a constraint so that the Bordered Scroll View - Table View.top is topStackView.bottom + 20, I get a constraint conflict. There is a hidden constraint where the Bordered Scroll View - Table View.t must be
topStackView.bottom + 8.

So, my question is where is this `+8` constraint coming from? I assume it must be from the NSScrollView that contains the table as all the components inside seem to have Translate Masks Into Constraints.

How can I properly use Auto Layout so achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done much with MacOS apps, but this may solve your issue...

Delete the `Bordered Scroll View - Table View.top is topStackView.bottom + 20` that you're trying to add.

You have them embedded in a vertical stack view - `mainStackView` - so set the `Spacing` on that stack view to `20`.

It may not look right in Storyboard / IB, but the result should be correct (I have two buttons at the top, but that won't make a difference):

[image]

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that the 8 separation was coming from the StackView. That makes more sense now. Thanks. Just need to figure out how to make the pop up item not extend all the way to the right